# event scheduler in mysql update if the count is one

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

I want to update the database if the count (mycnt) is 1 only not other number just 1 otherwise no update in database. I have done the following and i have no idea how to make the if condition inside this event scheduler. Please help me.
I have the following query.

```
select a.user_id, count(*) as mycnt 
from auction_details a 
inner join users u on a.user_id = u.user_id 
where PRODUCT_ID='1' 
GROUP BY bidprice 
order by bidprice;
```

The result comes as follow:

[image: Result as follow:]

In the event scheduler

```
BEGIN 
update products p join auction_details a on a.product_id = p.product_id 
join users u on u.user_id = a.user_id 
set p.winner = (select user_id from auction_details a where 
p.product_id = a.product_id order by bidprice DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE p.end_time <=NOW() and p.product_status='active';
End
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: @Madhur .. I want the database to update if the mycnt ans is 1. But i am unable to put the condition from where i can check my mycnt and update the database.

Comment: You should use Trigger instead

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I dont have any idea about the trigger in this mysql case. I am eage to do in event scheduler.

Comment: Do read up on Triggers. Your problem is a Trigger related (not event scheduler) - Event scheduler are to be used when you want to run a script at a particular time on a recurring basis

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya... Do u have any idea how i can do this in trigger. Can i use event scheduler after the trigger is used simultaneously.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya...... Actually this event is also the time related and in recurring basis.